# How to escape this sed command in a Jenkinsfile Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I'm doing a simple substitution, and this works fine at the command line:

```
sed "s/pub Url =.*/pub Url = 'https:\/\/example.com:3207';/g" myfile.ts
```

I'm trying to run it within a Jenkinsfile, and like 40 builds later I cannot get the escape quoting right.

**Pretty sure it will look something like this:**

`sh 'sed \\"s/pub Url =.*/pub Url = \\'https:\\\/\\\/example.com:3207\\';/g\\" myfile.ts'`

**Yet that results in the following error:**

`WorkflowScript: 4: unexpected char: '\' @ line 4, column 49.
   ub Url =.*/pub Url = \\'https:\\\/\\\/ex`

I feel like I've tried dozens of variants but nothing is working.

Here is among the most common errors I'm getting: which points to escaping issue

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'

I really just need a pipeline expert that can likely see exactly what I'm doing wrong and know where to quote it.

As noted here: https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4 this is not uncommon to fight this type of stuff in the pipeline files and it seems like it's just trial and error.

Comment: Could you put the first `sed` that works in a shell script, and then run that from the Jenkinsfile? Your second sample is bordering on unreadable, so you may be doing yourself a favour if you opt out of all that escaping... `:-)`

Comment: If you must do it from the Jenkinsfile, do you get the stated error with the sample you have provided? The question is a bit vague, since you say you've tried "something like this" and "dozens of variants", and it is not clear if the sample here produces the error here.

Comment: I've edited the question. I think I'm close to a solution though by simplifying the sed command and slowly building it up.

Comment: You do not need to use `/` as the delimiter for `sed`. You could use something that isn't in your source or replacement string like possibly `_` or `|` which may make it easier (some examples [here](http://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/)).

Comment: Good point, that might clean it up a bit, thanks @mkobit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after much trial and error, this is working.

Looks like I had to use **triple single quotes** around the command. Good thing I don't need to interpolate!

`sh '''sed \"s/pub Url =.*/pub Url = \\'https:\\/\\/example.com:3207\\';/g\" afile.txt'''`

Hope this is helpful to someone in the future that's fighting this!

Comment: You also reduced the back slashes in the HTTPS scheme to two (from three), which I was going to mention.

Comment: The `\"`s are wrong, but harmless. The Jenkinsfile eats the backslashes so the shell never sees them. But they don't provide any value, and probably add confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Absurdly, through trial and error, I learned that backslashes need to be doubled even inside triple single quotes in a `Jenkinsfile`. So the mechanical solution to your problem would look like

```
sh '''sed "s/pub Url =.*/pub Url = 'https:\\/\\/example.com:3207';/g" myfile.ts'''
```

However, you can avoid the backslashitis by using a different delimiter. Just make sure you choose one which doesn't occur in the text you need to process.

```
sh '''sed "s%pub Url =.*%pub Url = 'https://example.com:3207';%g" myfile.ts'''
```

A more complex scenario is when you try to use backreferences in `sed`. If you naively try

```
sh '''sed 's/foo\(bar\|baz\)/quux\1/' file'''
```

you get

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 17.
sh '''sed 's/foo\(bar\|baz\)/quux\1/' file'''
                 ^
```

Wrong as it looks, the solution is to double those backslashes.

```
sh '''sed 's/foo\\(bar\\|baz\\)/quux\\1/' file'''
```

Comment: (Or if you have `sed -E`, use fewer backslashes; but `\\1` in the substitution still requires them doubled.)

Answer (score -1):

To add more on this... I had an issue with `sed -i 's/\_/\//g' abc.txt` command running fine in CLI but resulting in an *`unxpected char \`* error in jenkins, so, i had to replace this:

```
sed -i 's/\_/\//g' abc.txt
```

with

```
sed -i "s/\\_/\\//g" abc.txt
```

To remove this error from jenkins.